# htmlBox inserting

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add custom buttons in htmlBox ver 4

Their example produces and `alert()` and this is working.

Here is my start on an email link insertion:

```
var email = { 
    icon:"email.png",
    tooltip:"Email",
    command:function(){ 
        var emailTX = prompt('Enter the email address','');
        if (emailTX!='') { 
            insert_text(emailTX); 
        }
    }
}
```

I realise that 'insert_text' is not enough.
How to insert into the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first get a reference to the textbox.  There are a variety of ways to do this, such as document.getElementById, document.getElementsByName.  Or, IMO, better still to utilize a library such a jQuery which normalizes all of this into a standardized low-quirks syntax.

Let's use the easiest example, getElementById...

If your textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea id="foo" name="bar"></textarea>
```

The referencing code would simply be:

```
var pEl = document.getElementById('foo');
pEl.value = emailTX;
```

Comment: Thanks for both the edit and the answer. I feel quite welcomed.
Each user-defined command in HtmlBox is directly related to a specific textarea - ta-1 ta-2 etc.

There are a few htmlBox questions on this forum - so here I am :)

I guess the question is what is the htmlBox-specific command to insert text. This also seems somewhat jquery related - something new to me.

There is no htmlBox forum :(

I also need to read up on formatting in this forum.. Thanks

Comment: @Arfa if this answer was helpful to you, mark it as 'correct' otherwise people might stop give answers to your questions :)